# Ways to have synced offline working data in Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, firebase, cloud

I have an android application which uses SQLite database (stored in APK) for storing offline working data. The app is used only in offline mode.

Now I want to create iOS version and I want to implement idea of synced databases on both platforms - Change database on server and it will update databases in device when will be online

My first idea was to replace SQLite to Firebase Realtime database but there is a problem with offline mode. Is there a way to cache the whole JSON for offline use?

Or is it easier to use a cloud for storing SQLite database and implement syncing with new versions of the database?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database client automatically downloads the data at these locations and keeps it in sync even if the reference has no active listeners. You can turn synchronization back off with the following line of code.

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
scoreRef.setPersistedEnabled();
```

But this need very first internet connection to sync, this will no enable data without that first request.

For detail about the offline capabilities, head out to the official doc link [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

Comment: I tried this way to store data for offline use (with combination setPersitanceEnabled to true) but it does not work:
1. open app
2. wait to load data
3. turn off internet connection
4. kill app
5. open app
6. data is not loaded